# Import a specific package inside a GitHub repository

Tags: go

## Intention

I intend to import exactly this package (subdirectory) to reuse its methods and types:

https://github.com/hemantasapkota/go-convexhull/tree/master/convexhull

Which is inside this repository:

https://github.com/hemantasapkota/go-convexhull

## Tried

I tried to import the whole repository:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/hemantasapkota/go-convexhull"
)
```

But `go get github.com/hemantasapkota/go-convexhull` is throwing errors. Since [its `main.go` file](https://github.com/hemantasapkota/go-convexhull/blob/master/main.go) contains `import "github.com/hemantasapkota/glu"` which is a private repository.

## Question

How can I import just the package `convexhull` inside a sub-directory of that repository? I mean, I don't need its `main.go` and its troubles.

Of course, I can copy over the files of `convexhull` sub-directory/package into my project. But I'm looking for a way to just simply *import* it from GitHub. Any idea?

Comment: import "github.com/hemantasapkota/go-convexhull/convexhull". Please take the Tour of Go and read https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started

Comment: @Volker I tried it. It's not working. I'll update with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/hemantasapkota/go-convexhull/convexhull"
)
```

However, when building, I received this error which I need to figure out:

```
Build Error: go test -c -o /tmp/__debug_bin930480706 -gcflags all=-N -l .
package printer/app/threed/detect/dental
    imports github.com/hemantasapkota/go-convexhull/convexhull
    imports github.com/go-gl/gl: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/m3/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-gl/gl@v0.0.0-20190320180904-bf2b1f2f34d7 (exit status 1)
```

Comment: Looks like the error has nothing to do with how import is done.